# openssl_x509_export_to_file : cannot get cert from parameter 1

Tags: php, openssl

I have an Apple Push Notification Development Push SSL Certificate generated by iOS Dev Center, by a certificate signing request .

I would like to use a PHP to convert certificate format. In Terminal / shell, I can execute this command to convert the certificate format :

```
openssl x509 -in aps_developer_identity.cer -inform der -out push_cert.pem
```

In PHP, I have:

```
$result = openssl_x509_export_to_file('/path/to/aps_developer_identity.cer', '/path/to/push_cert.pem');
```

However, PHP issues a warning:

```
openssl_x509_export_to_file() : cannot get cert from parameter 1
```

In [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.certparams.php), it said that the 1st parameter can be file path to the certificate file.

Given that:

- the certificate exists and accessible by the PHP script,
- the output path is valid and has write permission, and
- PHP openssl module is installed
- using PHP 5.3.10
- using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

What could be the problem?

Comment: You're trying to convert from a binary DER to a base64 PEM?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [phpseclib, a pure PHP X.509 implementation](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/b242259d17b0f56614a3fa7736b7834d1129c3e6/phpseclib/File/X509.php#L1534):

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n" .
chunk_split(base64_encode($cert), 64) .
'-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
```